# php file read function

Tags: php, file-read

I am using the following file read

```
$myFile = "file.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
fclose($fh);
echo $theData;
```

problem is file.txt is generating dynamically and is in different folder so how do I call it in fopen ?
I am trying

```
$fh = fopen(/path/to/$myFile, 'r');
```

but obviously its not working and giving me error

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '/',
```

how to rectify this and include my path ?

Comment: surround `/path/to/$myFile` with `"`

Comment: @PLB It works But further giving me error PHP Warning: filesize() [<a href='function.filesize'>function.filesize</a>]: stat failed and PHP Warning: fread() [<a href='function.fread'>function.fread</a>]: Length parameter must be greater than 0

Comment: Make sure that you use `fread("/path/to/$myFile")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$myPath = "/path/to/file/";
$myFile = "file.txt";
$fh = fopen($myPath.$myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
fclose($fh);
echo $theData;
```

I haven't tested it, but I guess it will work that way...

Comment: It works But further giving me error
PHP Warning:  filesize() [<a href='function.filesize'>function.filesize</a>]: stat failed and
PHP Warning:  fread() [<a href='function.fread'>function.fread</a>]: Length parameter must be greater than 0

Comment: You have to change the 4th line to `$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myPath.$myFile));`

Answer (score 4):

This is a simpler way:

```
$theData = file_get_contents("/path/to/file/" . $myFile);
```

Comment: It works But further giving me error PHP Warning: filesize() [<a href='function.filesize'>function.filesize</a>]: stat failed and PHP Warning: fread() [<a href='function.fread'>function.fread</a>]: Length parameter must be greater than 0 – user1561466 just now edit

Comment: With this way you do not need to open the file, stat it and all the other stuff, this returns the file contents with a single command.

Answer (score 3):

First off, it'd be simper just to use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

As to the file path, that needs to be a string, i.e.:

```
$fh = fopen("/path/to/".$myFile, 'r');
```

Comment: Always use single quotes for simple strings and you never have to worry about escaping...

Comment: @inVader False. `$myStr = 'Matt\'s string';`

Comment: @Matt - Right, yeah... but nevertheless, single quotes are the way to go if you don't have variables or special characters.

Comment: @inVader Agreed. I was just pointing out information that might confuse a newbie.

Comment: Single quotes are also faster in PHP because it doesn't have to parse them for variables.

Comment: That's a myth, if you don't have any `$` signs in it, there's no measurable difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to solve this problem in my own way. Hope this will help you.

```
<?php

$myFile = "folder/file.txt";
$myHandle = fopen($myFile, "r");

$myData = fread($myHandle, filesize($myFile));
$rows = explode(" ", $myData);

foreach($rows as $row) 
{
    print $row;
}

fclose($myHandle);

?>
```